# Exception dispatching input event, while calling startActivity

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

There are several related question already asked on StackOverflow and other forums. But, still this is causing and none of the solution is working for me. Also, I would like to state that I am using device 13'3 inch Braun Tablet.

Flow of application as per Activity,

`A` Activity calling `B` Activity and from `B` I am calling A Activity with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and there after process is repeated for Activities from Activity `A` to Activity `B`. Below is more detailed explanation

I am calling my MainActivity from a dialog for updating database as below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.IS_UPDATE_DATA), true);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And after that I am updating my database from a web-service call using AsyncTask and on completion of update I am using below code to startActivity from `onTouch()` of Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CategoryActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

This is causing below crash everytime,

```
01-29 20:21:44.631: E/InputEventReceiver(3213): Exception dispatching input event.
01-29 20:21:44.631: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1892)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1412)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3368)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3603)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3571)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at com.brodos.app.storeship.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:857)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7258)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2470)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1633)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2428)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2418)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7443)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchPointerEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2323)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3526)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3471)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4612)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4591)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4683)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5063)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-29 20:21:44.651: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3213):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Let me know if anyone can guide or has a solution for it. Also, let me know if anything is missing in question to be added.

Comment: i guess there is null pointer error at line number 857

Comment: It'd help, if you name OS version you running. I'm looking through ActivityManagerNative class and can't get which particular line caused NPE, once 1892 is not matching the one I'm looking into.

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov its 4.2.2

Comment: @PankajNimgade its native crash, I debugged and my intent is not null

Comment: @LalitPoptani can you add the complete code for the onTouch method? or the specific line pointed by the stack trace (MainActivity.java:857).

Comment: @kevinkl3 its crashing at `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: It would be great if you could add the complete code. It would be easier for us to see where the logcat points to

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes sorry but can't add 1100 lines code

Comment: where does the dialog will be shown?

Comment: Screenshots might help @LalitPoptani

Comment: If you can't post all the lines of code here, consider creating a gist on github or some other external hosting.  There is just not enough information here to diagnose.

Comment: I would suggest two things 1. debug for value of mContext. and 2. check after commenting pending transition line

Comment: @VivekMishra tried both, still didn't work!

Comment: do you have value in mContext?

Comment: yes I do have value in mContext

Comment: TRY CALLING mContext.startActivity() then

Comment: alreadyyyy tried it and its not working!!!!!

Comment: Can you please post your MainActivity and CategoryActivity?

Comment: Is this problem specific to that device??

Comment: just a suggestion : could please replace the variable **mContext**  to **MainActivity.this**  and debug it.

Comment: please share where you have added on touch... Is any on touchlistener null possibly?

Comment: @AnsalAli yes its problem of specific device, and I already tried using `MainActivity.this` as well

Comment: @Lalit Poptani so that every thing works perfectly on every other devices with 13.3 inch or higher display or smaller display. Na?

Comment: @LalitPoptani could please put that line of 'startActivity(intent);' inside a try catch block.., and print the stacktrace caught there. That might be something different to this since parceble class knows a few exception types; anything else gets translated into a base RuntimeException.   Try this and let us know your results:-)

Answer (score 2):

I have been through a quite similar to yours, and the solution has been like this:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(mIntent);
    mIntent.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

Comment: This won't work in my case as I want to start another activity in onTouch Event and why you are asking me to check `savedInstanceState == null`, I nevertheless want to start another activity always in my onTouch Event

Comment: I don't know who upvoted the answer, i reversed the comparaison!

Comment: Anyway, `savedInstanceState != null` is checked only to make sure we have a saved `Context`, which will fire the `startActivity(mIntent);` that should be saved to be secure and to be sure it's not the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

As you are running a AsyncTask, I think you need to start your activity in `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask()`.

Comment: Okay, well! What you mean is unclear. He told us `... call using AsyncTask and on completion of update I am using below code ...` and that is basically what i guess He meant

Comment: @lalit-poptani are you executing your onTouch() as venkat530 mentioned?